# Can Classes refer to each other?

Tags: c++, oop

I have some classes that are sequentially declared in the same file, however, I would like them to refer to each other.  However, classes can only be declared by classes that are above them.

Can I do this by separating them into different .h files and have them `#include` each other as need be?  Or can this be done whilst keeping them in the same file>

Or is this bad practice?

(Specifically, I have one instance of a class A that needs to keep track of multiple instances of class B of a different class-type that may try to interact with class A in no particular order; I need to keep the feedback specific to the class B that is trying to talk to that ONE instantiation of class A...)

Comment: Are you talking about the [tag:observer-pattern]?

Comment: Why yes... yes I think I very well may be....

Comment: Then you need to read this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals2.html

Comment: I'm not quite at that stage in the project, but thank you... I'll look into that!

Comment: If you're trying to (re-)implement the Observer pattern, then you *are* at that stage in the project. Or even a little bit past it. Save yourself some coding!

Comment: Oh no, this project is getting transferred to be part of another project that will implement it, lol.  I'm just trying to design this robustly, sir....

Answer (score 6):

As long as by "refer" you mean as pointer, this should work:

```
class Foo;

class Bar {
  Foo* p;
};

class Foo {
  Bar* p;
};
```

Comment: I tried to pass a reference to class Foo (ie, this) to a subroutine in class Bar - is this allowed, sir?

Comment: Forget the "sir" :) Sure, that should work. Generally those subroutines (methods) should be defined outside the class definitions, so they know the contents of both classes.

Answer (score 5):

You can forward declare classes and them define them later in the file:

```
class A;

class B
{
    // As pointed out by syam this will have to be an A* or A& not just of type A.
    // If this line were:
    // A myA
    // The compiler gives error: field ‘myA’ has incomplete type
    A* myA;
};

class A {};
```

If at any point you want to access methods or attributes in `A` from a method in `B` then you have to make sure that those methods are defined after the definition of `A`.

```
class A;

class B
{
    A& myA;
    int getAValue(void); // Can't use myA.value here as value is not declared yet.
};

class A
{
public:
    int value;
};

int B::getAValue(void) {return myA.value;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could even introduce a self-referential pointer:

```
class Foo {
    Foo* parent;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
class A;

class B {
private:
    A *parent;
public:
    B() {
        this->parent = 0;
    }
    B(A *parent) {
        this->parent = parent;
    }
    void erase();
};

class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> members;
public:
    void add(const B &x) { members.push_back(x); }
    B *getArray() {
        B *rv = new B[members.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<members.size();++i)
            rv[i] = members[i];
        return rv;
    }
    void remove(B *member) {
        for(std::vector<B>::iterator i = members.begin(); i != members.end(); ++i) {
            if(&(*i) == member) {
                members.erase(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

void B::erase() {
    if(parent)
        parent->remove(this);
}
```

The key points:

- I've declared B first so B can work with instances of A.
- I've forward-declared A, though, so the compiler knows it's a valid class. This allows B to keep a pointer to the instance of B.
- However, any methods in B that refer to A need to appear *after* the definition of A. Otherwise, you'll get `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A’` or similar.